# Cannot build "cyrus-sasl-2.1.23" on SUSE Linux 10.0

Tags: linux, svn, md5, digest, suse

I downloaded the source code from "ftp://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/cyrus-mail/".

Configure went well but when i build I end up with following errors:

```
digestmd5.c:852: error: 'des_context_t' has no member named 'keysched'

digestmd5.c:853: error: 'des_context_t' has no member named 'keysched2'

digestmd5.c:854: error: 'des_context_t' has no member named 'ivec'

digestmd5.c:855: error: 'DES_DECRYPT' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i guess configuration issues.
I configured it with following settings and it worked.

./configure --prefix= (PATH) --exec-prefix=(PATH) --with-dblib=no --without-des --with-openssl=(PATH)